# partials of a term resulting in same RHS

Tags: functions, partial-derivative

Does a term V exist $\ni$

$$
\frac{\partial\,V}{\partial\,x}= c_{1}\,x\,y 
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\,V}{\partial\,y}=c_{2}\,x\,y 
$$
where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are constants and $c_{1} \ne c_{2}$

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial\,V}{\partial\,x}= c_{1}\,x\,y 
$$
Hense $\:V=\frac{c_1}{2}x^2y+f(y)$
$$
\frac{\partial\,V}{\partial\,y}=c_{2}\,x\,y 
$$
Hense $\:V=\frac{c_2}{2}xy^2+g(x)$
$$\frac{c_1}{2}x^2y+f(y)=\frac{c_2}{2}xy^2+g(x)$$
which is impossible.

.

Another proof :

$$
\frac{\partial\,V}{\partial\,x}= c_{1}\,x\,y 
$$
Hense $\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial x \partial y}= c_{1}\,x$
$$
\frac{\partial\,V}{\partial\,y}=c_{2}\,x\,y 
$$
Hense $\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial x \partial y}= c_{2}\,y$
$$c_{1}\,x=c_{2}\,y$$
which is impossible.